# Undo or Redo on specific lines only

Tags: mac, undo

I am working on a file and made some changes I'd like to undo. Is there anyway that I can undo changes that were made in the part of the file where my insertion point currently is? I do not want to undo the changes I made in other parts of the file, only on this specific line.

This would come in handy when working on large files, because I can go back to one specific place and only undo changes for that one area.

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Mac OSX 10.9.2

Any help is appreciated. I tried searching Google but found nothing. I think that I do not know the terms for this kind of thing (if there are any).

Comment: I would save the changes as a new file, undo the changes, save again as a different file, then DIFF the 2 files and merge the changes you want. But no... the undo function is reverse-sequential only, as far as I know.

Comment: I concur with Wutanut. @Wutnaut, you should post this as an answer so the OP can accept it and we can up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the undo function is reverse-sequential only.

I would save the changes as a new file, undo the changes, save again as a different file, then DIFF the 2 files and merge the changes you want.